# What is the purpose of passing apicontroller constructor parameter as Func<> delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func, webapi

We have some code that we now own that was originally written by a vendor. It's a .NET WebApi project that is an extension. That is, the main API application passes the startup to this module for it to register itself and dependencies, it's using Autofac for DI.

The ApiContoller constructors are written like so:

public Func ProductService { get; private set; }
        public Func AccountService { get; private set; }

```
    public ProductController(Func<IProductService> productService, Func<IAccountService> accountService)
    {

        AccountService = accountService;
        ProductService = productService;
    }
```

and then the methods are called elsewhere like so:

```
    ProductService().AddItem(item);
```

I've found some similar questions on here, but were more directed toward a specific issue. My question is, what could possibly be the purpose for this? I understand using a delegate to encapsulate a function, but this is pointing to an instance of a type. Is there a difference in the way it gets instantiated perhaps? Thanks for any feedback you can give.

Comment: With `Func<>` you don't have to implement your own delegates. If you did not have `Func<>` you would have to implement two of them here, to pass these method pointers as input parameters to your method.  Look at the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: Possibly used as a workaround to prevent your DI container from `new`ing up instances of the service, and its dependencies, and their dependencies, etc, etc. for actions that don't make use of that service. Having to instantiate the entire dependency chain for every service used by your class leads to increased processing time. When you want to actually use an instance of the service, then you invoke the delegate, and that will result in that specific dependency chain being materialized.

Comment: Usually dependencies will be created before controller object creation.
Above code is trying to restrict object instantiation after controller object creation.

There should be some reason for that, is there any specific logic within `ProductService()` call?

Can you share the code inside `ProductService()`